# Invoke multiple lambda functions in a single eventbridge schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

Is it possible to invoke multiple lambda functions in a single eventbridge schedule?
I want to invoke one lambda function for staging env and one for production env using the same schedule.

Seems wasteful to create dedicated schedule per lambda functions.